# Android 12 froze, does this leak IP address with VPN killswitches enabled?

Tags: wi-fi, security, networking, mobile-network, vpn

I have a VPN running with Android's 'always-on' VPN feature enabled, and the 'block connections without VPN' feature enabled. My device running Android 12 recently froze and wouldn't respond. I had to restart it by holding the volume down and power off button.

My question is, in this frozen/non-responsive state, would the 'VPN killswitches' have leaked my true IP address? I've searched everywhere for this information and couldn't find it anywhere, so I would appreciate any help I could get.

I couldn't produce any logs because I eventually did a factory reset.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered as a "frozen/non-responsive state" can mean everything from frozen UI to total system with errors, may be because of flipped RAM bits. Thus anything could happen on such a corrupted system.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your response. All I know is, I opened an app and the device became completely frozen. Do you think this would have leaked my IP?

Comment: It can only be answered as opinions.  Does it not depend on what you were doing at that time, what browsers or apps you were using, what sites you were visiting, if you were downloading files.  Plus it has happened already.  May as well deal with it.